# What's the difference returning a QuerySet or a list of it?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models `Book` and `User` with a foreign key on `Book`. And in one of my API endpoints I return the following QuerySet:

```
return User.objects.get(pk=user_id).posts.all()
```

The result is correctly rendered on the browser. If I change the line to (using a list):

```
return list(User.objects.get(pk=user_id).posts.all())
```

the output result is the same.

Since QuerySet is lazy-load (being executed only when evaluated), my question is:

what's the difference in terms of memory or performance between the two approaches? Or will return and list have the same effect (evaluating the QuerySet)? What's the best approach I should use?

I read the docs but it wasn't very clear to me what happens when the QuerySet is returned or a list of it.

Extra info: I'm using Ninja API based on FastAPI, but the question would be the same for context data of a django view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My gut feeling is that the performance would be nearly the same in most cases. Did you try benchmarking it? Is there any visible perf difference?

Comment: I've tried benchmarking using this (decorator)[ https://github.com/goutomroy/django_select_prefetch_related/blob/master/apps/bookstore/decorators.py]. One extra database hit is made using list.

Comment: If the return is always used, I don't think there would be any difference in performance. Is the benchmark executed only on this method that returns the queryset or also on the user of this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate another queryset from a queryset, by applying further filters.

```
qs = User.objects.get(pk=user_id).posts.all()

...

qs = qs.exclude( topic='brexit') # this is now an ex-topic.
```

It's more work to process a list into a shorter list. Also inefficient, if the further filtering involves spanning relationships into other tables whose objects you have not prefetched. (i.e. the N+1 problem).

You can also extend a queryset using `.union()` etc.

On the other hand, it can be useful to feed an "annotated" queryset into a template context using a generator function to relate adjacent objects.

```
def new_month_annotator( qs):
   month = '000000'
   for obj in qs.order_by('date')
       obj_month = obj.date.strftime('%Y%M')
       obj.new_month = (obj_month != month)
       yield obj
       month = obj_month
```

If you iterate over this in a template you can now easily generate month labels within a forloop. (You could equally easily do this to a list of objects, either using a generator or just by modifying the objects).